# Can we use RabbitMQ free with magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, rabbit-mq

Can we use RabbitMQ free with Magento 2?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Yes, you can. I have done this before.

Comment: @NathaOdedara, I too successfully installed it in my local, and it's working fine. Now I want to move this to my production server.

Comment: @NathaOdedara, do i need to pay any subscription fee or using RabbitMQ in production environment

Comment: Nope, no need of any fees.